# ruby: How to dynamically inherent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a Stats class which I will use to extract some stats from two different objects. Each object needs to use its own methods to get the stats. Let me show you what I mean:

```
class Stats
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
    #^^ missing code here ^^
  end
end

class Table
  def initialize(table)
      @object = table
  end

  def sum
     @object.sum / 2 * 0.5
  end  
end

class Chair
  def initialize(chair)
      @object = chair
  end

  def sum
     @object.sum / 23 * 1.5
  end  
end
```

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
stats = Stats.new(Table.find(343))
stats.sum # 3.4

stats = Stats.new(Chair.find(343))
stats.sum # 98.4
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: what should the  `Table.find(343)` return?

Comment: Table is an active record object. So is Chair.

Comment: That, the return values are the `Table` instances, can't be seen of the code. please add proper inheritance for the post.

Comment: So `How can I achieve this?` that should just values in the db

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What is wrong with just `Table.find(343).sum`/`Chair.find(343).sum`?

Answer (score 2):

Since both `Table` and `Chair` implement sum, just delegate the `sum` method to `@object`

```
class Stats
  def initialize(object)
    @object = object
  end

  def sum
    @object.sum
  end
end
```